# How to send json with multipart file in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I've stumbled across similar questions and have understood that @RequestBody cannot be sent with a multipart file in Spring. Can anyone explain why is that?

Some suggested using @RequestPart for both data and file and I embraced it. 
My controller is as follows:

```
@PostMapping(value = "localhost:8080/medicine", consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
@ResponseBody
public BooleanResponse saveMedicineData(@RequestPart(value = "file") MultipartFile file, @RequestPart Medicine medicine) {
...
}
```

Medicine is a entity class with Lombok annotations. Its implemented as follows:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "medicine")
@Entity
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Medicine {

private Long id;

private String name;

private String url;
}
```

Upon making a post request to this url on postman I get this exception:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1533476503168,
     "status": 415,
     "error": "Unsupported Media Type",
    "exception": 
    "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
     "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",
     "path": "/medicine"
```

}

How do I deal with this error?

Comment: the media type in postman is `application/octet-stream`, while your method on the server side expects media type: `multipart/form-data`. It has to be the same in order for it to work. If you change the media type on the server, it should work fine.

Comment: @MerveSahin I have tried with both of the content-types in postman: application/octet-stream and multipart/form-data. For octet-stream I get
"exception": "org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException",
 "message": "Content type 'application/octet-stream' not supported",

Comment: What do you get with multipart/form-data? You also might post a capture of the raw request.

Comment: @dbreaux with multipart/form-data I get the error stated in the question.

Comment: So whether your postman test uses octet-stream or form-data, both report that octet-stream isn't supported?

Comment: @dbreaux exactly